# Differential of $\phi(t) = (e^{it}, e^{i\alpha t})$ is injective

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given the map $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S_1\times S_1$ defined by $t\mapsto  (e^{it}, e^{i\alpha t})$; $\alpha$ is an irrational number and $S_1$ is the complex unit circle.

I want to show that $d\phi|_t$ is injective (or called non-singular) at each $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then together with $\phi$ is $C^\infty$ and injective, this would imply $(\mathbb{R},\phi)$ is a submanifold of  $S_1\times S_1$.

What I wanted to do is to write down the image vector in the basis of $T(S_1\times S_1)$ explicitly,
$$d\phi|_t \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg|_t\right) = \sum_i \frac{\partial (x_i \circ \phi)}{\partial r}\bigg |_t \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\phi_t} $$
Is this the correct approach, and is there a commonly used (global) coordinate system on $S_1\times S_1$ so I could calculate $\frac{\partial (x_i \circ \phi)}{\partial r}$?

Comment: Of course you can use charts, but you can also do this directly, thinking of this as a map $\phi\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$. ... And I do not like the word non-singular when dimensions don't match.

Comment: Note that injectivity of $d\phi$ is not sufficient for the image being a submanifold, this is only true locally.

Comment: The _first component_ of $d\phi$ is already non-vanishing.

Comment: @AndreasCap Yes, I checked that $\phi$ it self is injective.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I think i got it, and I posted the answer below.

Comment: Since the image of $\phi$ is dense in $S_1\times S_1$, why do you think this image is a sub manifold?

Comment: @zhw. Not the image is a submanifold, that is $(\phi(\mathbb{R}), i)$ where $i$ is the inclusion map is a submanifold of $S_1\times S_1$. The question is showing that $(\mathbb{R}, \phi)$ is a dense submanifold.

Comment: Also injectivity of $\phi$ together with injectivity of $d\phi$ is not sufficient for the image being a submanifold. You only get what is usually called an immersed submanifold from these conditions. Your example produces a so-called initial submanifold, which is better behaved than general immersed submanifolds.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggested, we can look at the differential of $d\phi|_t$ as 
$$d\phi|_t = (2\pi i e^{2\pi i t} dr|_t, 2\pi i \alpha e^{2\pi i \alpha t} dr|_t),$$
only looking at the first component, we see that when acting on any nonzero vector of the form $c\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, it will not be zero, thus it is injective.